# how to consume a .net webservice from a C++ application?

Tags: c#, c++, web-services

I have a c++ application which checks the information about the printers in a given network. I need to store this information in database, using a webservice in another .net web application. But I m new to c++ and i have no idea how i can make a call to the webmethod in the webservice using c++. There is no add web reference option in the c++ application.

can anybody suggest me a good tutorial for this? 
My application is a win32 console application.

Thanks,
Subrat

Answer (score 2):

There is an MSDN article using Visual Studio 2005 named [Walkthrough: Accessing an XML Web Service Using C++ and the CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14hykb68%28VS.80%29.aspx) that should be similar to using Visual Studio 2008 C++.

Comment: Not sure but is Subrat using CLR C++?

Comment: I am not. Its a win32 console application.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Axis](http://ws.apache.org/axis/cpp/index.html) from Apache to connect to web services.

Answer (score 0):

Since you imply Windows, you might look at WinInet (look for it in msdn).  WinInet is a very powerful and feature rich http client but also complicated to use, especially in asynchronous mode.

Answer (score 0):

SOAP messages that are exchanged between client and server are basically XML documents and they are sent via HTTP (they are in the body of HTTP message). If you know the format of SOAP request and response you could use [WinHttp API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384273%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), or more general [WinINet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383630%28VS.85%29.aspx). Yet another solution is [IXMLHTTPRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759148%28VS.85%29.aspx). Be prepared to parse XMLs yourself, probably by using [MSXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

ATL Server is not available in VS2008 (it is released as [community project](http://atlserver.codeplex.com/) so am not sure how keen Microsoft is to support this technology).

I used WinINet on WinCE to access Apache Axis2/C web service.

Comment: Is there any sample tutorial on Wininet? The webservice I am using returns an array of string. Can i get this using WinINet?

Comment: MSDN has a good set of articles regarding WinINet, starting at this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385331(v=VS.85).aspx. If you know the format of SOAP response body, you can parse it and extract data returned by web method (set of strings in your case). You can use WireShark or Fiddler to see structure of SOAP messages.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [gSoap](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html) - a great open-source, C/C++ library for accessing web services. I've used this extensively for accessing services written in .Net. Commercial and not-for-profit licenses available.

You just need the wsdl file/url and it will generate the client / server code for you. From the web site:

> The gSOAP distribution package
>   includes two compiler tools to develop
>   your applications:
>
> 1. The 'wsdl2h' WSDL
>      parser. This tool converts WSDLs and
>      XSD files into annotated C/C++
>      definitions.
> 2. The 'soapcpp2' stub and
>      skeleton compiler. This tool generates
>      RPC code and XML serializers from the
>      annotated C/C++ definitions.
>
> The 'wsdl2h' parser converts WSDL into
>   gSOAP header file specifications of
>   Web services. This specification gives
>   a C/C++ transparent view of the
>   server's functionality. The header
>   file is processed by 'soapcpp2' to
>   generate the source code stubs and
>   skeletons to invoke the service or
>   build a new service based on the WSDL.